# Can a lady who was celibate for most of her life be a Brahmacharya?

Tags: karma, dharma, women

Is it possible for a lady to be a brahmacharya if she was obliged by family duty to enter a marriage that lasted only a few weeks, after which she remained celibate the rest of her life? In the eyes of God, what would be her condition?